# ParNewGC taking very long

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

[image]

We are seeing unreasonably large pause time for young generation GC. we use 8G of heap size with young generation at 4 GB. Does anyone have pointers as to how we can find out the reason behind such high pause times ?

We use -XX:ParallelGCThreads=48 and its running on a 48 core machine. we are using oracle idk 1.7_0_79 on centOS 6

complete list of options:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:SurvivorRatio=8"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseTLAB"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+AggressiveOpts"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:ConcGCThreads=48"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:ParallelGCThreads=48"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:-ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseGCTaskAffinity"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:ParGCCardsPerStrideChunk=65536"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:CMSScheduleRemarkEdenSizeThreshold=104857600"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:CMSRescanMultiple=32768"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:CMSConcMarkMultiple=32768"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure"
```

Comment: considering that you haven't posted any JVM options: more detailed logging might help

Comment: those 4GB/s GC throughput seem anemic for a 48core system. is other stuff running on the machine or maybe you're getting bitten by NUMA?

Comment: @anishek I would look at the `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=48` parameter. Although you have 48 cores setting parallelGCThreads as 48 doesn't seems a good choice. Bring it down to around 20-24 and try it. `For N <= 8 parallel GC will use just as many, i.e., N GC threads. For N > 8 available processors, the number of GC threads will be computed as 3+5N/8` as quoted in [link](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-6-throughput-collector/). Similarly `ConcGCThreads`. Also if too many objects are getting promoted to tenured gen reduce `-XX:SurvivorRatio`  value, to say, 6 or so & try

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu i will try and reduce the number of threads though this is the only process running on that node there is nothing else, its a dedicated machine, the number of objects getting promoted to tenured space is very less. Since cassandra might be creating a number of small objects for keys I have currently tried to modify the max heap size = 16 GB and new heap size = 12GB, waiting for it to run for some more time before plotting the graphs

Comment: @the8472 you are correct that 4GB/s GC throughput is horrible as we have other machines in the cluster with same config,which are giving 76 GB/s. all the hardware configurations are same on these machines.

Comment: Well, can you post the GC logs? at least an excerpt covering the exceptionally long pauses. Also, some of your GC options seem like cargo-culting, have you actually measured the impact of adding them? Also, have you monitored system performance outside the JVM (primarily IO and CPU load)

Comment: I will try and extract the logs if possible or will post a complete log. It would be great of you to point some of the cargo-cult opts above? as for measuring the impact for all the options, that would take a lot of time so i have been reading on them, took a lot of them as starting point for measuring cassandra performance and then tweaking them down the line. Systems are monitored for i/o and CPU load and the long pauses happen on machines with high CPU load, I/o is not a problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions for you

- I would increase the heap size.  8 GB isn't much and it is 57% full. You may get better results if it is 30% full. e.g. try 16 GB.
- The GC works better when you put it under less load. One way to do this is to either a) increase the Eden size so more objects have a chance to die early, and less objects are likely to get promoted to tenured space, or b) decrease the eden size, depending on you object allocation usage.  I tend to increase, but I have seen examples where decreasing it helped.
- Reduce your allocation rate will improve not only the pause times, but improve the speed between pauses.  Use a memory profiler like Flight Recorder to look at your allocations and see where it can be reduced.
- Consider using the G1 collector in Java 8.  This can reduce/control the pause times dramatically (provided the machine has space CPU which it appears to do)

Comment: This is the usage for Apache cassandra, I can try increasing the heap to 16GB though everyone at cassandra mailing list has asked me not to go beyond 8 GB. I can not really control the allocation rate as its internal to cassandra neither can i move to G1 as of now as we are on older version os cassandra. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: @anishek If you are using cassandra, you should try Azul Zing. This is a use case where Zing has made a big difference for issues such as this.  The problem is with the amount you use, so provided usage is no higher, you can give your program more head room.